# Is that possible to run IIS's w3wp.exe in limited user account?

Tags: delphi, iis, isapi, w3wp, datasnap

I am using Windows 7 and IIS 7.  I am writing Delphi DataSnap ISAPI.  I wish to trace bugs occurs in my ISAPI dll.

I learn using "w3wp.exe -debug" may help to debug ISAPI dll in Delphi IDE.  However, I wish to debug my ISAPI in limited user account instead of administrator group.

I have set access right to folder "C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config" before running w3wp.exe.  However, I still encounter problem start w3wp.exe.  Here is the event log:

```
The World Wide Web Publishing Service (WWW Service) did not register the URL prefix http://*:80/ for site 1. The site has been disabled. The data field contains the error number.
```

I have stop my IIS service prior to running w3wp.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've switched to [xxm](http://xxm.sourceforge.net/) to create my ISAPI extensions, it not only provides auto-update on my dll's, I use the InternetExplorer protocol-handler to debug it.

Answer (score 0):

I use [idDebugger](http://users.telenet.be/ws36637/) to run and debug my ISAPI applications.  It runs quite well, and I don't see why you wouldn't be able to attach to it running in a limited user account.  The nice thing about using idDebugger is that its an executable rather than a service, so no more stopping and starting the service each time you want to recompile.